# Can't properly retrieve objects from NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I will be putting a variety of things in this mutable array, but first I am just trying to make sure it works by putting in strings, and then pulling out the strings. Here is my code

```
str1=@"1";
str2=@"2";
str3=@"3";
NSMutableArray *testArray;
[testArray addObject:str1];
[testArray addObject:str2];
[testArray addObject:str3];

retrieve =[testArray objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"the test number is %@",retrieve);
```

The problem is that my string:retrieve equals "null" after receiving the string from the array. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, I've looked at Apple's documentation but I'm having trouble  making sense of it. I know I must be interacting with the array incorrectly, but I'm not sure how exactly. Help will be appreciated.
-Thank you!

Comment: testArray = [NSMutableArray new] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not initialize your `testArray`:

```
NSMutableArray *testArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

You can populate the array using new syntax. If you needed mutability only to add the three items, you could use a non-mutable array instead, like this:

```
NSArray *testArray = @[ @"1", @"2", @"3"];
```

If you do need mutability, call `mutableCopy`:

```
NSMutableArray *testArray = [@[ @"1", @"2", @"3"] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's because `testArray` is `nil`. you should change the 4th line to

```
NSMutableArray *testArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Answer (score 0):

You array is nil.

You are missing 
NSMutableArray *testArray = [NSMutableArray array];

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what others are telling you:

This line

```
NSMutableArray *testArray;
```

Does not create an array. It creates a pointer variable that can be used to point to a mutable array. It starts out containing a zero value (nil, points to nothing.)

It's like a postal address that points to an empty lot.

You need to create (allocate) and initialize a mutable array object in order to use it. (Continuing our analogy, you have to build a house and put a mailbox in front of it before the address becomes valid.)

So you need to say:

```
testArray = [@[ @"1", @"2", @"3"] mutableCopy];
```

Breaking that down:

The inner part,

```
@[ @"1", @"2", @"3"]
```

Creates an immutable array that contains 3 string objects.

Then we ask the immutable array to create a mutable copy of itself. We save the address of that newly created mutable array into the pointer variable testArray.

We could do it in 3 steps:

```
NSMutableArray *testArray;
NSArray *tempArray = @[ @"1", @"2", @"3"];
testArray = [tempArray mutableCopy];
```

Or all at once, like @dasblinkenlight's code:

```
NSMutableArray *testArray = [@[ @"1", @"2", @"3"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Thanks Duncan! it makes sense now, some how i didn't grasp that concept by reading apples docs.